# Installing Ubuntu on a broken MacBook?

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, usb, mac

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my broken mac book which isn't booting now (I had Ubuntu on it before and I tried installing Arch on it which I think messed up with partitioning). So when I switch on the mac, it displays a grey screen with a question mark in a folder at the start-up. Then, I took it to the mac store where they said that the hard drive is done, but I thought I can just boot it from a USB, Now, I am currently on my Windows computer (Windows XP) and I have a 16GB USB where I used unetbootin to copy Ubuntu (the actual .ISO onto the USB). But when I plug the USB into my mac it doesn't boot and it goes back to the same grayed screen with a question mark in a folder.

What can I do to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, If the store techs have said that the hard drive is done (busted), then how are you planning to install any operating system on it despite Ubuntu?

Secondly, I cannot exactly predict whether this is something to meddle with hardware or software issue as I'm not physically presented to diagnose the issue.

But before that I'd suggest you to refer "**[A flashing question mark appears when you start your Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1440)**" KB article from the official Apple website itself to acknowledge. And also, **[Apple support community](https://discussions.apple.com/article/TS1440)**, to find out similar threads.

Tip: I cannot confirm whether this would work as I've never tested it on a Mac. But make sure you've created a proper bootable USB with proper instruction. Then plugin the USB, hold down the **option** key while switching on the system to boot into the menu selection. If you're able, then have a look at **[How to install Ubuntu on MacBook using USB Stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick)**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've already done that, I've tried all the commands listed, nothing happens, so I assume it's just done. Maybe it's just time to buy a new computer, seeing as how this macbook is old as hell.

Comment: Try to inquire from mac store whether you're able to replace an HDD or similar to get this fixed. Else if what you said will solve your issue, then you better look into it. Also, mark answered if this served you to avoid this getting queued in questions. :)

Comment: They said it would be a $200 job for them to fix it, but said I can just go to my local computer store and get a hard drive for a cheaper price.

And will do, once I figure out how to :) Thanks for the help